# An impossible task? Reverse current/short circuit protection not only for load but also for power supply

Tags: power-supply, short-circuit, circuit-protection, load, reverse-polarity

This is a magnetic phone charger.  It's a USB cable that plugs into a standard 5V phone-type charger.  The magnetic "plug" has a (+) center-pin and a (-) round metal as the ground with a magnet behind it.  The receiving load-side "socket" mirrors the power-supply plug by having a spring-loaded (+) center-pin and also (-) metal ring as the ground with a magnet behind it.  Has no (D+/D-) data lines, only power.

Unfortunately, (with some deliberate effort) I have discovered that the physical design DOES ALLOW for an inadvertent **short-circuit** by having the "plug's" center-pin touch the round ground metal of the mating "socket" while at the same time it's own round metal ground touching the center-pin of the "socket".

I can protect the receiving load circuit with a diode, or a MOSFET, or other common reverse-current/voltage protection.  But is there any way to prevent the power-supply itself from getting shorted out?  The 5V power-supply/charger can be anything, since this is just a USB cable.

The only way I can think of protecting a connected 5V power supply/charger (let's assume it does not have one built-in) is to somehow channel away/absorb the short-circuit current somewhere on the receiving load side of the circuit by offering a lower path of resistance, while also making sure that the load-side of the circuit is not damaged either.

What say you?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Something is wrong about your assumptions. A short-circuit on the supply side does *not* lead to a current that needs to be shunted/absorbed away from the load. It creates a high current that overloads the supply. Carefully draw the schematic of the components with a wire indicating the short-circuit connection, and see where you have currents flowing.

Comment: The load will not be damaged if the supply is shorted. The load will not even be aware of the short-circuit, and will be totally unable to do anything about it. Let the supply fend for itself. It is pretty rare to send a supply out into the world that can't handle a brief accidental short-circuit.

Comment: @nanofarad Yes, a short overloads the supply and causes an over-current in the supply side.  And that's what I am trying to solve by leading away the current from the supply...since I have no control over what is being used as a power supply for my load. I can protect the load, but if someone shorts the plug they can damage their power-supply. I hoped to have some way mitigate that with my circuit on the load side.

Comment: @mkeith - "Let the supply fend for itself. It is pretty rare to send a supply out into the world that can't handle a brief accidental short-circuit."  I agree with you.  But being  a devil's advocate here: if someone like me with their own-designed gadgets plugs in their power-supply that is not protected...

Comment: If you produce a short on the supply side with the plugs, there's nothing your load can do about it. You need to redesign the plug so that shortcuts become impossible.

Comment: @TommyS Since you are using magnets, have you attempted anything with axial self-aligning magnets? (Concentric alternating cylinders, for example.) With several alternations (more is better), it gets almost impossible to make them mis-align. (Have a look [here](https://www.amazingmagnets.com/c-160-aling-polymagnets.aspx). I just searched to see if someone was already doing this for you.)

Comment: @ PMF.   So, there is no way to protect the supply other than make sure physically the plug cannot short itself, or make sure that supply is designed with a protection already built-in (which they all should be).  I am looking into other types of magnetic plugs that are available which are safer by design..

Comment: The protection for the supply MUST be in series with the cable before the short circuit. Something like a fuse or PTC or electronic over-current detection back at the supply is the best way to do it. There just isn't a way to do it at the load. The load will never know that the supply has been shorted.

Comment: @jonk   These are commercial magnetic plugs that I am adapting for my gadget. I wanted to make it idiot-proof.  I ordered another type that has an insulated raised mating island with the pins inside and the magnet surrounds it. No physically exposed pins.  Did not arrive yet.

Comment: @ mkeith.   I think you have something there: since this is a commercial USB cable there could be a small USB-to-USB adapter at the USB end with short-protection inside.  Or just make my own USB cable (by reusing the magnet plug end) with short protection built-in the cable itself before the external power supply's USB connection.. But. it's kind of convoluted.  Let's see...I am waiting for another type of magnet plug that seems to be designed better.

Comment: @jonk  Thank you, Looked up the link to the magnets. Interesting concept for the specially designed magnets.  Seems like some real brute force and deliberate action would be needed to create a short with them.

Comment: Any respectable PSU these days has some form of s/c protection, even just a fuse. Even if you make a perfect plug, cables fail occasionally. This all looks like trying to solve a problem from the wrong end as far as I can see.

Comment: @TommyS If the power supply is shorted, this causes an over-current. By attempting to redirect the overcurrent, you are *still* causing an over-current in the supply, regardless of whether the current is "absorbed" by the short circuit, a bag of wet sand, a dummy load, etc. You need to **interrupt** the current, not send it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to do something with the load side circuitry to protect the supply from overcurrent caused by shorts in your magnetic connector. As stated in the comments, you can't. It is not physically possible. Possible options that would allow you to continue using this connector include installing a PTC fuse or similar circuit in between the power supply and the offending connector, or ensure you're always using a supply that can handle shorts.